# my server doesnt deploy the latest git code on azure

Tags: azure

My server doesn't deploy the latest git code on azure. 
I checked in the web.config file as well - it just doesn't pick up the latest code. It has been working fine for the last 3 months.

the address is pastg.azurewebsites.net

Can you please help?

Comment: Have you checked in the portal for errors?

Comment: You'll need to provide more info than that (and no need to publicize your site name): Logs, screenshots...

Comment: what log would u like to see? i need a reputation of 10 to publish screen shots....its not a code error - yr server just doesnt deploy hte latest git code the way it used to 2 days ago

Comment: there are no errors that I can see - it just ignores the latest code checked in git

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to see if it helps:

- Go to the dashboard for the site
- Click 'delete git repository'
- Click 'Set up deployment from source control' and re-set up the connection

You don't specify it in your question, but I assume you are linking to github?